# grid item text alignment

Tags: html, css

I have a grid with label tags for each item, arranged in rows and columns.  When I click a label (which turns on a corresponding checkbox or radio button), I want the label to be in larger bold text. So far, so good, I have that in the code below (but for simplicity, I made a small grid, and only one actual checkbox).

The problem arises when I click the label and the text gets the larger bold font.... it no longer is aligned with the unchecked items.  I've tried various combinations of align- and justify- -items and -content without success, but maybe there is some combination that will work?  Or maybe I need some other surrounding tags?

I'd be happy with either centered or baseline vertical alignment, and would like centered horizontal alignment.

EDIT: horizontal alignment turned out to be easy, but I was stumped with the vertical alignment.

EDIT 2:  So if I take away the label height, and add justify-items: center;  stuff gets aligned nicely, but the grid row height jumps around annoyingly when things get selected. This is unacceptable. Is there a different way to control the grid row height, besides its content height?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
:root {
font-size: 12pt;
}
div {
display:inline-grid;
grid-template-rows: repeat(3,1fr);
grid-auto-flow: column;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;
}
label {
height: 1.6rem;
width: 1.6rem;
}
input:checked ~ div [for=ck] {
font-size: 1.6rem;
font-weight: 900;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>test</h1>
    <input type=checkbox id=ck>
    <br>
    <div>
      <label>1</label>
      <label>2</label>
      <label>3</label>
      <label>4</label>
      <label for=ck>5</label>
      <label>6</label>
      <label>7</label>
      <label>8</label>
      <label>9</label>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh for dumb.  I must have been tired when I tried all those options, and wasn't thinking logically.  After simplifying enough to post this question, the 2nd edit made it obvious.  Instead of using the 1fr stuff for the heights, just put the 1.6rem there instead of in the labels.